# add total sum of one column every set of related rows

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to receive sql output like this:

```
ORDER #  |   LINE #   |   PRICE
---------------------------------
AAA      |    1       |    20   
AAA      |    2       |    30
AAA      |    3       |    10
TOTAL_PRICE = 60    
BBB      |    1       |    50 
BBB      |    2       |    20
TOTAL_PRICE = 70
GRAND_TOTAL = 130
```

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Both are same table or different table ?

Comment: There is only one table with all order lines without the total calculation

Comment: That's data presentation, not really what SQL is made for. Play around with UNION ALL, group by/sum etc, dummycolumns for order etc. and it can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregating by order and adding the grand total.

```
    select order
         , sum(price) total
      from table
  group by order
 union all
    select 'grand total' order
         , sum(price) total
      from table
         ;
```

This provides the raw data in tabular structure. For generating a specifically formatted outpout  you will need a reporting tool. some rdbms have command line clients that can assist you with this (eg. oracle's sqlplus), if you don't expect too fancy a result.

**Edit** (per OP's comment):

Including the original order lines and presenting the rows in the desired order requires additional machinery:

```
    select *
      from (
                select order                seq
                     , order
                     , line
                     , price                total
                  from table
             union all
                select order || '-0'        seq
                     , 'TL('||order||')'    order
                     , null                 line
                     , total
                  from (
                            select order
                                 , sum(price)           total
                              from table
                          group by order
                       )
             union all
                select 'ZZZZZZ-9'           seq
                     , grand total'         order
                     , null                 line
                     , sum(price)           total
                  from table
               )
  order by seq
         ;
```

The actual composition of the `seq` column depends on the actual format of order codes (rarely a problem, since their format is usually constrained in a well-defined way).

As said before, for fancier outputs you are probably better off using a suitable tool.

Comment: will I have that way the order lines listed as well?

Comment: No. That's when you need another UNION ALL with a group by.

Answer (score 0):

Please also Try:

```
SELECT Order, line, SUM(price) total_price
 FROM table_name
GROUP BY order, line, price WITH ROLLUP;
```

**hope this helps.**

Comment: This is the preferred way to build the resultset but the syntax depends on the sql dialect, iirc.